# Primary Scenarios and Use cases

Tags: use-cases, scenarios

Should you write a primary scenario for every use case in a use case diagram separately or write one primary scenario that incorporates all the use cases in the diagram?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your definitions are, but I'm pretty sure the convention is this:

- **Use case diagram** - a diagram associating actors to use cases.
- **Use case** - a set of actions, including variants (ie, the primary and alternative paths).
- **Scenario** - a specific sequence of action (ie, a single path - primary or not).

So by these definitions, you should write a (primary) scenario for each use case.